# How do we change the location for a specific dependency defined in pom.xml for a Java project?

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, pom.xml

I know we can change the location for all dependencies by  tag, but I need to place specific dependencies in another location during the build?

Comment: What do you mean by "location"? Are you referring to the local Maven repository cache on your file system.

Comment: The jars defined in pox.xml currently are being generated in target\lib directory. I want some of these jars to be generated in lib and others in some other directory.

Comment: Sorry, you're confusing me even more. Are you asking about *dependencies*, i.e. third-party jar *downloaded* from the web and cached in your local Maven repository, or are you asking about your own jar files *generated* by the maven build script?

Comment: I am talking about jars generated by the maven build script.

Answer (score 0):

You can move dependencies using maven-antrun-plugin

in this example I create a new folder named lib2 then I move dependencieA.jar into lib2

```
....
<plugins>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>move</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <target>
                            <mkdir dir="target/lib2" />
                            <move file="target/lib/dependencieA.jar" tofile="target/lib2/dependencieA.jar" /> 
                        </target>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
<plugins>
...
```

Comment: When I do this, I get the specified dependencies in the target/lib2 folder. But I am also using maven-ear-plugin to generate a .ear package for this build. And I am not seeing the dependencies in lib2 folder in target/file.ear. Do I need to change the goal on any of the plugins?

Comment: do you want to also copy the dependencies into a ear?

Comment: Yes, I want to copy dependencies into the final ear.